# filter with map throws null pointer exception if one of the object has null values in Java

Tags: java, filter, lambda, hashmap

I am trying to iterate my map and filter out its a list using this method but if I don't have value available for that property(**id**) it throws a null pointer exception in Java.

How I can filter in such a way that it iterates my hashmap and filter out the value if the id matches with the given code?

```
data.entrySet().stream()
       .filter(a -> a.getValue().stream()
           .anyMatch(l->l.id.equals(code)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             e -> e.getKey(),
             e -> e.getValue()));
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], input, as well as the full stack trace and clarify your question.

Comment: Why did you remove the stack trace from your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add null checks before validating code.  Second, it may be better to use `Objects::equals` as it is null-safe:

```java
data.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> Objects.nonNull(e.getValue())
        && e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(l -> Objects.equals(code, l.id))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue
    ));
```

Comment: It is not correct to use Objects.nonNull in place of `e.getValue() != null`.  That method is for use as a method reference, not as a replacement for a normal Java operator.